# SQL update a column with minimum value in a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update the MD_ID column with the minimum value in the DESC group.
For example, I want all the rows where DESC=Language to get MD_ID=21 as min(21, 163, 287)=21. To simplify, it is always the MD_ID associated with SOURCE=1.

The data looks like this:

```
MD_ID|SOURCE|DESC           |MSG |SEGMNT|FIELD
  21 |1     |Language       |A11 |PID   |33
 163 |2     |Language       |A11 |PID   |33
 287 |3     |Language       |A11 |PID   |33
  22 |1     |Sex            |B22 |MSH   |8
 145 |2     |Sex            |B22 |MSH   |8
 171 |3     |Sex            |B22 |MSH   |8
  23 |1     |Marital Status |C33 |NK1   |16
 145 |2     |Marital Status |C33 |NK1   |16
 289 |3     |Marital Status |C33 |NK1   |1
  24 |1     |Religion       |D44 |GT1   |7
 167 |2     |Religion       |D44 |GT1   |7
 292 |3     |Religion       |D44 |GT1   |7
```

---

I need it to look like this:

```
MD_ID|SOURCE|DESC           |MSG |SEGMNT|FIELD
  21 |1     |Language       |A11 |PID   |33
  21 |2     |Language       |A11 |PID   |33
  21 |3     |Language       |A11 |PID   |33
  22 |1     |Sex            |B22 |MSH   |8
  22 |2     |Sex            |B22 |MSH   |8
  22 |3     |Sex            |B22 |MSH   |8
  23 |1     |Marital Status |C33 |NK1   |16
  23 |2     |Marital Status |C33 |NK1   |16
  23 |3     |Marital Status |C33 |NK1   |1
  24 |1     |Religion       |D44 |GT1   |7
  24 |2     |Religion       |D44 |GT1   |7
  24 |3     |Religion       |D44 |GT1   |7
```

Comment: What do you mean by *that group*?

Comment: also, DESC is a reserved keyword in ORA, did you even test this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable t
    SET MD_ID = (SELECT MD_ID
                     FROM YourTable t2
                     WHERE t2.DESC = t.DESC
                         AND t2.SOURCE = 1)
```